# SetState to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have trouble with changing state of the parent with setState. First I have my RootView.jsx with:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
sizes: [
                {label: "90x50mm", isChecked: false, number: 10},
                {label: "85x55mm", isChecked: false, number: 12}
            ],
            ratings: [
                {label: "OneStar", isChecked: false, imgSrc: 'images/Rating1Star.svg', counter: 22},
                {label: "TwoStars", isChecked: false, imgSrc: 'images/Rating2Stars.svg', counter: 18},
                {label: "ThreeStars", isChecked: false, imgSrc: 'images/Rating3Stars.svg', counter: 34},
                {label: "FourStars", isChecked: false, imgSrc: 'images/Rating4Stars.svg', counter: 27}
            ],
            favorites: [
                {label: "Only favorites", isChecked: false, number: 12}
            ]
}
```

and

```
_setProps() {
    this.setState({
        isChecked: !this.state.isChecked
    });
}
```

then for all elements Im creating checkboxes in different component, example:

```
return (
            this.props.sizes.map((size, idx) => {
                return (
                    <Checkbox
                        key={"size"+idx}
                        label={size.label}
                        checked={size.isChecked}
                        number={size.number}
                        _setProps={size.props._setProps()}
                    />
                )
            })
        )
```

with my Checkbox component, in which I have:

```
 render () {
        return (
            <div className="Checkbox">
                <form>
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        id="check"
                        onClick={this.props._setProps.bind(this)}
                    />
                    <img src={this.props.imgSrc}/>
                    <label htmlFor="check" id="label">{this.props.label}</label>
                    <label htmlFor="check" id="number">{this.props.number}</label>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

And with my onClick I would like to change the state of isChecked for one element in array in RootView.jsx

Is it possible?

Comment: you want to update ischecked for every array?

Comment: no, only for this one element that was clicked

Comment: but ischecked is inside sizes,ratings and favorites

Comment: yes, but for every element in every array im creating a checkbox (first for "90x50mm", second for "85x55mm' etc) and i would like to change state of isChecked only for one element every time that it was clicked

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to pass the index of the array element that your creating a checkbox element with

```
return (
            this.props.sizes.map((size, idx) => {
                return (
                    <Checkbox
                        key={"size"+idx}
                        index={idx}
                        label={size.label}
                        checked={size.isChecked}
                        number={size.number}
                        _setProps={this.props._setProps.bind(this)}
                    />
                )
            })
        )
```

And in your checkbox component send this index as an argument

```
render () {
    return (
        <div className="Checkbox">
            <form>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    id="check"
                    onClick={this.props._setProps.bind(this, this.props.index)}
                />
                <img src={this.props.imgSrc}/>
                <label htmlFor="check" id="label">{this.props.label}</label>
                <label htmlFor="check" id="number">{this.props.number}</label>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And change the state as follows

```
_setProps(idx) {
    var sizes = this.state.sizes;
    sizes[idx]["ischecked"] = !sizes[idx]["ischecked"];
    this.setState({
        sizes: sizes
    });
}
```

I hope it helps you solve the problem

Comment: Thanks, but this solution is solving only a part of that problem but not a whole problem. I dont want to change the state of isSelected only for item in sizes array. I have few arrays with different filters and you can click on filter from array sizes or from array ratings or from few more and I want it to work with all of my arrays... Hope its understandable

Comment: you can do similar for other array also

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I was hoping that maybe there is some way to get this feature to work for each array, so I need only one not 5 or 10 of them

Comment: What you can do is define a property for the checkbox that tells which array it belongs to and then in the _setProps function you can perform conditional actions similar to whats done for the sizes array. Let me know if it helps you

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Unfortunately, I do not know why but your solution does not work. I had to change it a little bit, but still receive error: Cannot read property 'isChecked' of undefined, here is my code: 

     _setProps(idx) {
     var sizes = this.state.sizes;
     sizes[idx].isChecked = !sizes[idx].isChecked;   <------- HERE!
this.setState({
      sizes: sizes
  });
 }

Comment: Check two things, in setProps do you get the index, if not try (e, idx) or (idx, e), in parameters. Also don't forget to bind _SetProps function otherwise it wont receive state